# Command 'gradle -v' not found in VS Code terminal/PowerShell but in standalone terminal/PowerShell

Tags: powershell, gradle, visual-studio-code, terminal, command

When I run: `PS C:\Users\myname\Desktop> gradle -v` in my VSCode Terminal I get the exception
`gradle : The term 'gradle' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet ...`

When I run the command in PowerShell everything works like expected. Therefore I assume that my path in the environment variable settings is correct.

Why VSCode Terminal don't know the command `gradle -v`?

EDIT:
The terminal outside of VS Code also works like expected!

Comment: Maybe the path isn't set up properly in the integral shell? There's a [config](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_terminal-profiles) for profiles.

Answer (score 1):

Try on the bash terminal it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I observed the very same error in both Visual Studio Code Terminal and InteliJ Idea Terminal, for all `gradlew` commands (like `build`, `clean`, etc.), each command works as expected when I use `CMD` but not in any IDE,
using /gradle-6.9.2, jdk 11.0.13.

I recently learned that InteliJ runs its `Gradle` seperate than the console one, with the usage of gradle-wrapper (a.k.a `Gradlew`) with different kinds of variables than the terminal. It also makes version control of gradle and similar components easier by collecting them under build.gradle.kts file

Setting `GRADLE_HOME` to `C:\Gradle\gradle-6.9.2` in my system variables did solve the problem in both inteliJ and Visual Studio Code Terminal.

Comment: Maybe this should be a comment but no answer. But thank you.